# FFmpeg on windows 7, encode video in mp4 for HTML 5 video fail

Tags: video, windows-7, encoding, ffmpeg, html5-video

I try to encode my video with FFmpeg, to convert to mp4.
But the video doesn't work on html 5. I don't understand why.

I found this command on the web and I tried it:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i wildlife.wmv -b 1500k -vpre slow -vpre baseline -vcode libx264 \
  -g 30 wildlife.mp4
```

But it fails, and I have this error :

```
File for preset 'slow' not found
```

I check the folder "presets" and the preset is on the folder, so I don't understand why it's telling me this error.
I tried with the complete path, it fails too.

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -i wildlife.wmv -b:v 1500k -preset slow -profile:v baseline \
  -vcodec libx264 -g 30 wildlife.mp4
```

- your `-vcode` should be `-vcodec`
- `-vpre slow` should be `-preset slow`
- `-vpre baseline` should be `-profile:v baseline`
- `-b 1500k` should be `-b:v 1500k`

To answer the comments, until
[Firefox 21](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)
the best format for compatibility across browsers would be WebM. YouTube uses this format as well.

Comment: Thanks, the command works perfectly! 
But I really don't understand why the element <video> doesn't want to play my encoded video! 
this is my HTML :
`<video width=680 min-height=390 controls>  \
             <source src="/Videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
            </video>`

Comment: I'm trying to make HTML 5 Video like this website: 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MMS/2013/KEY1#time=0h0m0s
When you click on "format" under the video. You can see that :
"HTML5
For browsers that support H.264 MP4 or WebM video playback such as:
IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 5+, or Safari 4+."
What do you advise ?

Comment: Do you know what would be the command ffmpeg for getting WebM format please? 
Thanks

Comment: @manonthemoon That would be a separate question, but there's information on that available, so no need to re-ask. Please look at this answer of mine: [Converting video to WebM with ffmpeg/avconv](http://superuser.com/questions/556463/converting-video-to-webm-with-ffmpeg-avconv/556677#556677) – and the [vpx Encoding Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide) on the FFmpeg wiki.